# Given an permutation $a$ in $S_8$  how to find $a^{14}$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Given the following exchange in $S_8$:
$$a = \left(\begin{array}{cccccccc} 
    1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 7& 8\\ 
    2& 5& 8& 3& 1& 7& 6& 4 
\end{array}\right)$$

I need to find what is $a^{14}$ .

First, I found $a$, in the following sequence :
$$a = (1\ 2\ 5) (3\ 8\ 4) (6\ 7).$$

But how can I calculate $a^{14}$ using the above ?

Regards,

Comment: Hint: start with $(1,2,5)^3$, or very easy $(6,7)^2$.

Comment: That's the thing : I don't exactly understand how to calculate the following : (125) (125) , or (125) (125) (125) , can you please explain ?

Comment: setup 8 things in front of you and permute element 6 and 7, this is $(6,7)$, permute twice for $(6,7)^2$. Or more difficult: Put thing 1 on place 2, thing 2 on place 5 and thing 5 on 1. This is $(1,2,5)$. Happy shuffling!

Comment: So if I'm not mistaken , (6,7)^2 equals (6) ?

Comment: Hmm, in fact I think $(6)$ might count as a representation of the identity, but I won't write it like that. Maybe $(6)(7)$ suits better...

Comment: Then (6 7)^2=(6)(7) , and (1 2 5) (1 2 5) = (5 1 2) ? and the last one (5 1 2) (1 2 5) = (2 1 5) ? thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are disjoint cycles, then $\sigma\tau=\tau\sigma$; in particular, for every integer $k$, we have $(\sigma\tau)^k = \sigma^k\tau^k$.

So the first observation is that you can compute $a^{14}$ by computing $(1\ 2\ 5)^{14}$, $(3\ 8\ 4)^{14}$, and $(6\ 7)^{14}$ separately.

The second observation is that if $\sigma^n$ is the identity, and $a\equiv \pmod{n}$, then $\sigma^a = \sigma^b$.

Since $(1\ 2\ 5)^{3}$, $(3\ 8\ 4)^3$, and $(6\ 7)^2$ are the identity, you only need to compute $(1\ 2\ 5)^k$ where $k$ is *any* number congruent to $14$ modulo $3$; $(3\ 8\ 4)^s$ where $s$ is *any* number congruent to $14$ modulo $3$; and $(6\ 7)^m$ where $m$ is *any* number congruent to $14$ modulo $2$.

I'll leave that to you.

Comment: (1 2 5)^3 = (1 5 2) , (3 8 4)^3 = (3 4 8) , (6 7)=(6)(7) , is this right ? if so , what now ? thanks

Comment: @ron: No; $(1\ 2\ 5)^3$ is the identity. $(3\ 8\ 4)^3$ is the identity. $(6\ 7) = (6\ 7)$. I *think* you didn't write what you meant. Were you trying to write the result of $(1\ 2\ 5)^{14}$, $(3\ 8 \ 4)^{14}$, and $(6\ 7)^{14}$? If *so*, then yes. Then $$a^{14} = \Bigl( (1\ 2\ 5)(3\ 8\ 4)(6\ 7)\Bigr)^{14} = (1\ 2\ 5)^{14}(3\ 8\ 4)^{14}(6\ 7)^{14};$$and since you know the far right hand side, you know what $a^{14}$ is.

Comment: Then I didn't get what you mean ,probably.When you say "the identity" then you mean "id" , right ? so a few questions: 1. what is the identity of (1 2 5)^3 ? 2. if what I wrote in my previous comment isn't correct , then how can I calculate what a^14 exact value ? thanks a lot!

Comment: @ron: $(1\ 2\ 5)^3$ is *the identity of $S_8$*. It's the permutation that sends every number to itself: just compute it! That's why what you wrote in your previous comment is incorrect. You wrote "$(1\ 2\ 5)^3 = (1\ 5\ 2)$." That's *wrong*. If you had written "$(1\ 2\ 5)^{14}=(1\ 5\ 2)$" **instead**, then that would have been *correct*. I *suspect* you made that mistake when you wrote down your first comment for *each* of the three permutations. And I *already* told you how to compute $a^{14}$ exactly, twice (once in the post, again in the previous comment).

Comment: Okay ,then : (3 8 4)^14 = (3 8 4)^2 = (3 4 8) ? but what about (6 7)^14 ? since 14 modulo 2 equals 0 , I get                (6 7)^14=(6 7)^0.

Comment: @ron: And $x^0$ is the identity element of the group for any $x$ in the group. Or, instead of using $0$, use $2$. Remember: you can use **any** number that is congruent to $14$ modulo $2$, not just the remainder.

Comment: I don't understand this statement "you can use any number that is congruent to 14 modulo 2, not just the remainder" - 14 modulo 2 equals 0 , then from what you're saying , I don't have to use 0 ? what does it mean "any number that is congruent to 14 modulo 2" ? much thanks !

Comment: @ron: By definition, if $n$ is a positive integer, then $a$ and $b$ are "congruent modulo $n$", written $a\equiv b \pmod{n}$, if and only if $a-b$ is a multiple of $n$. This happens if and only if $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when you divide them by $n$. So "any number that is congruent to $14$ modulo $2$" means "any $b$ such that $14-b$ is a multiple of $2$", which means "any $b$ that leaves a remainder of $0$ when divided by $2$", which means "any even number number". I'm not using the "modulo" **operation** that CS-types like, I'm using the modulo **relation**.